# Javascript escape quote in a function

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>untitled</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendToCart(a,b,c,d,f){
      alert(arguments[1].replace(/'/g, "\\'"))
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#" onclick="sendToCart('102','Lover's Combo','5.00','13','');return false">send to chart</a>
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone please tell me why alert is not working? It is working fine when I directly escape while passing value at the time of onclick but not working after reading from function?

Comment: There's an unescaped `'` in your second parameter. In fact the code highlighting in your own question shows exactly what the issue is. Edit: you actually seem to realize this, but not understand that the code is broken and thus will not do what you think it does.

Comment: Error is known, but the flow is like this only as I cannot change the parameter value.

Comment: Inline code is a terrible idea anyway; you need to escape this on the server-side.

Comment: I think the only solution is to rewrite the server code

Answer (score 0):

You will need to fix the server-side code to make sure you escape apostrophes. On server-side, depending on your server, you should have good means to escape apostrophes. If you are using PHP, you might want to call [addslashes](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_addslashes.asp). Or you can call a method in your server-side which replaces apostrophe with `\\'`

Answer (score -1):

The error occurs when the JavaScript parser reaches the `s` after the string literal `'Lover'`.

Your escape function runs later (or would, if the syntax error hadn't stopped further execution).

You can't fix a syntax error in your JavaScript source code by trying to apply regular expressions to it, from inside the same program, after the parse error has already been hit.

Comment: I know the actual error but I need some solution so that I can escape in function only rather in argument.

Comment: @MohdFaizan Not possible. If you construct a machine that is able to plug itself into a power outlet, it will still never run without being connected to power in the first place.

Comment: @MohdFaizan — I refer you back to the last sentence of the answer. Fix the `onclick` attribute so the JS doesn't have syntax errors in it in the first place.

Comment: I think the only solution is to rewrite the server code.

Comment: @MohdFaizan — Yes. If you are generating JS with server-side code, then you need to generate syntactically correct JS.